# carp_background_location и отправка геоданных через http.post

Tags: http, flutter, dart, background

Изучаю разработку приложений в flutter. Столкнулся с тем, что не могу разобраться как отправлять геоданные в фоновом режиме через http.post().

1. Я выбрал плагин "[carp_background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location)" для получения геоданных в фоновом режиме (использую [пример](https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location/example) этого плагина)
2. По нажатию кнопки я могу отправить эти данные через http.post().

Но как правильно отправить http.post() в фоновом режиме с данными от carp_background_location?
Я могу обойтись для этой задачи этим плагином (carp_background_location) или же мне нужно устанавливать дополнительные плагины типа WorkManager, background_fetch и т.д.?

Comment: В примере в `onData` можно добавить `http.post()` и как только будут приходить данные, он сам будет их отправлять на сервер. Также возможно нужно будет добавить `debounce` на запрос.

Comment: И да, не забывайте: `The plugin will not necessarily work if the app has been terminated.`

Comment: MiT, спасибо за ответ!
Добавил в onData как вы посоветовали и с debounce и без, но как только приложение уходит в фоновый режим - запросы через http.post() не уходят. Хотя сам плагин продолжает работать.

Comment: Чтобы я не делал в onData, то после ухода в фоновый режим - это не выполняется.

Comment: Потому что flutter не может работать напрямую в background (фоновый режим). Вам скорее всего нужен будет: https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

Comment: Спасибо. WorkManger подошел, но частично. Он запускает задачи минимум раз в 15 минут. Буду теперь думать как собирать геоданные за эти 15 минут и отправлять разом :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Перенос ответа из комментариев, чтобы закрыть вопрос.*

В примере в `onData` можно добавить `http.post()` и как только будут приходить данные, он сам будет их отправлять на сервер. Также возможно нужно будет добавить debounce на запрос (чтобы не делать одновременно много запросов).

`carp_background_location` не позволяет выполнять код фоновом режиме, а также:

> The plugin will not necessarily work if the app has been terminated.

По этому для всего что связанно с фоном, нужно использовать [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) или его аналоги.